# Remote config not updating from console

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am facing a strange problem when I try to update my remote config value from firebase console and try to publish those changes, I am getting an error **A general error occurred.**. This problem happens randomly and when I checked my network console for the response I am getting a 500 error.

Following is the JSON response

```
{ 
code: 500
message: "Internal error encountered."
status: "INTERNAL"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why downvote my question?

Comment: If this happens on the console, and it shows an error 500 (which is a server-side error), there is nothing any of us can do about it. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, and possibly (if it is reasonably reproducible) a bug report.

Comment: You're not the only one. We have the same problem. We cannot update Remote Config from dashboard either

Comment: @Mihai did you find any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Remote Config engineer here. We noticed some intermittent issues a few hours ago that we've since resolved. Thanks!

Comment: We're experiencing continued issues with projects that integrate Remote Config with Cloud Functions that is preventing publishes. (see https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Remote%20Config/19003 for more information) All other use cases are working fine.